# css shield for widget

Tags: css, bookmarklet

I'm creating a bookmarklet. It will display a widget on page. However, some existing css on page can effect to my widget. How to avoid this? I don't want to use iframe.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "effect to my widget". Do you mean "I don't want any other stuff on my page to modify/affect the widget in question"?

Comment: Why do you not want to use an iframe? They seem tailor-made to your current purpose.

Comment: @David Thomas: If I use iframe, I need to change all my javascript code.

Comment: I don't want to sound obnoxious but, that suggests (to me) that you should've used an `iframe` from the start...Ah well, @alex's answer should work well enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *localised* reset.

Take an [existing CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) (or roll your own), and namespace it by putting your widget's `id` (or class) in front of it.

### Example

#### HTML

```
<div id="my-bookmarklet-panel">...</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#my-bookmarklet-panel a,
#my-bookmarklet-panel div,
#my-bookmarklet-panel span {
    /* Reset rules */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make use of the !important statement in our widget CSS to protect your rules from overriding.